# Best way to structure C# Class

Tags: c#, class, object-model

I have the following Classes;

```
public class Hotel
{
   public int HotelId {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Address {get; set;}
   public string City{get; set;}
}

public class District
{
   public int DistrictId {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Then I need a class that can hold both DistrictId and HotelId as a pair so I thought of creating a class like below

```
public class HotelDistrict
{
   public int DistrictId {get; set;}
   public int HotelId {get; set;}
}
```

Is this the correct way to go ?  Or is their a better alternative ?

Comment: You could also use a `Dictionary<int, int>` where the key could be the district id and the value the hotel id.

Comment: Could you explain why do you need the class and how would you use it?

Comment: Yeah I thought of a Dictionary too, but is their a preferred / correct way ?

Comment: The HotelDistrict class is basically a representation of the data from a database table.

Comment: @Tommo1977, if there are more than one hotel in district `Dictionary` is not a good choice. Use `Lookup<TKey, TElement>`

Comment: An association class can make things explicit as opposed to a dictionary. Also a dictionary wouldn't allow m-to-n relationships and makes backward navigation difficult.

Comment: Are you sure this is a `m:n` relation? Doesn't feel natural to me to have a hotel be in multiple districts (in case that is the relation the objects are supposed to have).

Comment: No a hotel can only belong to 1 district

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That looks to much to a database table design. In OOP world, you normally add references to classes instead of just to ids.

Something like this

```
public class HotelDistrict
{
   public Distric District {get; set;}
   public Hotel Hotel {get; set;}
}
```

There is no silver bullet so there are exceptions for this rule but normally you want to avoid creating classes that smell so much to database tables.

Comment: I agree that it looks very much like an association table, but on the other hand, especially in terms of Domain-Driven Design, it can be favorable to use IDs, not objects, as references. In the end it's all about how loosely coupled and/or cohesive you want your objects to be.

Comment: Thanks this is what I thought would be the way, just a reference to the class referencing the properties I want.

Answer (score 7):

Hotel and District have `many to one relationship`. So, Hotel should have mapping to its corresponding District -

```
public class Hotel
{
   public int HotelId {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Address {get; set;}
   public string City{get; set;}
   public int DistrictId{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Although a reference directly to `District` would be preferred.

Comment: Yeah it can be get only property in class.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply store a reference to `District` in your `Hotel` or a `List<Hotel>` in your `District`. Typically, unless you are dealing with writing database models, you should not retain unique identifiers as you are doing. If this is a database model, then your solution is fine assuming you need to support a hotel in more than one district.

Comment: I'm using the Classes to hold data from a XML field that I get, which in turn I need to store in different database tables.

Comment: @Tommo1977 In that case, the one you have marked as the solution is good!

Answer (score 0):

For any reason, if you really need to go with the original `HotelDistrict` way, you actually don't need a new class, you could just use a `Tuple<Hotel, District>` to store pairs, and a list of those tuples (such as `List<Tuple<Hote, District>>`) to store a list of those pairs.

But as Rohit Vats stated, there is a *-1 relationship so it's better to have a reference to the district as a field, so I recommend his approach if you don't have a specific reason for using your original approach.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other excellent answers here you can also do the following if you prefer a more explicit domain model with loosely coupled objects. (I assume every single hotel can only be in one district at a time.)

```
class Hotel
    int HotelId
    int DistrictId
    ...

class District
    int DistrictId
    ...

class HotelsInDistrict
    int DistrictId
    List<int> HotelIds
```

The upside: It's loosely coupled, you don't need to fiddle with painful stuff like huge object graphs, lazy/eager loading and stuff. It' along the lines of the actual business domain instead of just data containers. It's loosely coupled and allows easy modification.

The downside: It doesn't easily maps to yourt database tables. But no real object model does if it's more than a data oriented bunch of "classes" that are mere representations of tables.

That said, there's a book I really recommend to everyone interested in object modelling:

- [Streamlined Object Modeling: Patterns, Rules, and Implementation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130668397)